# JSF 1.2: valueChangeListener event not returning newly selected value

Tags: java, jsf, valuechangelistener

I have this backing bean:

```
public class PageBean 
{
    private List<SelectItem> selectPages;
    private List<SelectItem> selectRowsPerPage;
    private String selectedPage;
    private String selectedRowsPerPage;
    private int pages = 0;

// getter methods
public boolean getRender()
{
    boolean rendered = pages > 0? true: false;
    return rendered;
}   

public List<SelectItem> getSelectPages() 
{
    int value = 0;

    selectPages = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i < (pages + 1); i++) 
    {
        if (i > 1) { value = i * 10; }
        selectPages.add(new SelectItem(Integer.toString(value), Integer.toString(i)));
    }   

    return selectPages;
}

public String getSelectedPage()
{
    if (selectedPage == null) {
        selectedPage = "1";
    }

    return selectedPage;
}

// setter methods
public void setSelectPages(List<SelectItem> selectPages) {
    this.selectPages = selectPages;
}  

public void setSelectedPage(String selectedPage) {
    this.selectedPage = selectedPage;
}    

// action methods
public void changePage(ValueChangeEvent event)
{
    PhaseId phase = event.getPhaseId();

    if (phase.equals(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION)) {
        System.out.println((String) event.getNewValue());
        setSelectedPage((String) event.getNewValue());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    } else {
        event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
        event.queue();
    } 
}    
}
```

And the h:selectOneMenu is:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="page" value="#{pageBean.selectedPage}"
   valueChangeListener="#{pageBean.changePage}" onchange="submit()">
   <f:selectItems value="#{pageBean.selectPages}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The above codes for the **changePage()** method do not return the new selected page value from the h:selectOneMenu. Instead, it returns the page value prior to submit. I don't understand why.

Can someone please help? Have been stuck on this for 2 days now.

Comment: this question got famous views for obvious reasons

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you're doing a redirect instead of a forward, while the bean is request scoped. A redirect creates a **new** request, hereby garbaging all initial request scoped attributes, including request scoped beans. It will thus cause recreation of request scoped bean with all default properties. To solve this problem, remove the `<redirect/>` entry from the `<navigation-case>` entry in `faces-config.xml`, if any.

If this is for pure page-to-page navigation, I'd recommend another approach for this. Get rid of the `valueChangeListener`, have the page URL's as SelectItem values and replace `submit()` with:

```
onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"
```

You namely don't want to use `POST` for simple page-to-page navigation.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** as per the comments, you actually want datatable pagination and this dropdown must instantly go to page X of the datatable at the same JSF page? In this case, forget my answer above, it wasn't clear from your question and I didn't realize that you want datatable pagination.

The as far posted information and code looks fine. Have you debugged the code to see what happens with property values? Isn't it nulled out afterwards? Is the correct value returned during render? Does the dropdown list return the expected items during render? That kind of trivial things. Maybe something else which you didn't post about is colliding with this all.

**Edit 2:** I actually created an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to see if it really works and as I expected, it just works. Your problem lies somewhere else. Maybe a buggy `Converter`? Maybe it was *actually* a redirect?

MyBean (request scoped):

```
public class MyBean {

    private Integer page;
    private List<SelectItem> pages = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    public MyBean() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            pages.add(new SelectItem((i == 1) ? i : (i * 10)));
        }
    }

    public void changePage(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION) {
            setPage((Integer) event.getNewValue());
        } else {
            event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
            event.queue();
        }
    }

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

}
```

(by the way, you used `String` instead of `Integer` which is imho the wrong type for numerical values, but here it works fine with `String` as well)

JSF page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.page}" onchange="submit()"
        valueChangeListener="#{myBean.changePage}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.pages}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

I used Mojarra 1.2_13 on Tomcat 6.0.20.

By the way, the `valueChangeListener` is entirely superfluous. It works as fine without it. JSF just sets the selected page during `Update Model Values` phase.

Comment: @BalusC: No I don't have <navigation-case> or <redirect/> directive defined in my faces-config.xml at all. When the onchange() method is called, this method grabs the selected page (plus 3 other selected values on the form) and pass all these back to the database for data retrieval. If I select page 2, the database should return record 11 to 20 as I'm limiting 10 records per page. The selectOneMenu should display page "2" after the form is submitted. Your pagination method in your blog is different to my requirement so I couldn't adopt it. Is the JS suggestion above the only solution?...

Comment: Oops! Apology for my typo above. The method above should read: onchange="pageChanged(), where pagechanged is a JavaScript function that's equal to: document.getElementById("Form1:btnSubmit").click();. The function behind btnSubmit is what I've described in my previous comment. I'm grateful to you or anyone else who can help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Can I add a h:inputHidden field to store the changed page value so when the form is submitted, I can retrieve the value from the hidden field. If this is possible, how can I define the getter/setter methods in a backing bean. I'm new to JSF so I really don't know how to do it this way. If you know, can you please provide some sample codes.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, after submit, the selectOneMenu is re-populated with the correct list of pages- but the previously selected page is not selected after submit ie. the first item on the list is re-selected. Also, in my getSelectedPage() method above, if the returned page value is null, then it's default to "1" (as I can't have page null). I think this is what happened when the form is re-submitted. Is it because I'm re-populating the pages with the getSelectPages() method? I wonder if that's why it's losing the previous selected page value during the JSF phases.

Comment: Run a debugger. I don't see a problem in the as far posted information. Something else is colliding with this.